# I don't understand Angular data binding at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've spent several hours trying minor variations of this code, and I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't.

Here's the scenario: I'm trying to present a list of registered users (which I'm getting with a simple database query that returns just a few columns), then when one user's name is clicked on, I'll retrieve more information about that user from the database, and present it in a different view. At the moment, I'm doing this with regular `<a>` elements with an `ng-click` directive that sets a value called `currentid`. Elsewhere in my code, I use `$watch()` to send out a new database query whenever `currentid` changes. That part seems to be working (I see the `console.log()` output from my watch callback, and the database query is spitting out the right data)... but sometimes `currentid` changes, and sometimes it doesn't, and I cannot figure out why.

- A jsfiddle where it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/aLcRL/11/
- A jsfiddle where it DOES work: http://jsfiddle.net/aLcRL/12/

(Click on the "rmunn" and "admin" links in the table: the "Currrent ID" value below should update. And please pardon the almost total lack of CSS; I'm a coder, not a graphics designer ("Dammit, Jim!"), and it's also very late in my timezone right now so I have no motivation to pretty this up. It's functional, it demonstrates the problem, and I'm going to leave it at that.)

The only difference between these two is that one is binding to `currentid`, and the other is binding to `vars.currentid`. Now, I understand why binding to `currentid` wouldn't work in the case of a parent and a child scope (the child's value would overshadow the parent's value); since I'm coming from a Python background, this makes sense to me (it's similar to how Python's instance namespaces can shadow the namespaces of anything defined on the class). But in this jsfiddle, I'm only using one controller -- aren't all these variables in the same scope?

I've been beating my head against this all day, and the several Stack Overflow answers I've tried to read (like [How does data binding work in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs) for example) have just left me even more confused: `$apply()` and `$digest()` and scopes, oh my! So if anyone can give me a nice simple beginner's guide to scopes in Angular (or point me to an already-written one that I've missed), I'd be very grateful.

"I've learned Clojure and Haskell, I can learn a simple Javascript framework," I thought. "This'll be easy." Boy, was I wrong. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into an issue where `ng-repeat` creates a child scope.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in data" blarg="{{user.id}}">
    <!-- currentid here is part of the ng-repeat child scope 
     and not your root scope -->
    <td><a href="#{{user.id}}" ng-click="currentid = user.id">{{user.userName}}</a></td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you need to access the parent scope you can use `$parent.currentid`

```
<a href="#{{user.id}}" ng-click="$parent.currentid = user.id">{{user.userName}}</a>
```

You need to use `$apply()` whenever you modify a value outside of the angular world.  For example using `setTimeout()` or a jQuery Plugin.  Calling `$apply()` alerts Angular to reevaluate the `scope` to see if anything changed and update accordingly.

Comment: There it is, right in the [ng-repeat documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat) -- "This directive creates new scope." Five little words that I completely missed earlier, which have such a large impact. Thanks; this completely explains the issues I was having.